# Проблема с заменой src при ошибке img используя jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Была задача: если по указаному пути img нет картинки, выводить другую картинку. По сути, изменить иконку ошибки img. Чтобы в каждом тэге не писать onerror решил использовать js для всех img.

Код написан, но он работает очень странно. Если обновить страницу через ctrl+F5, замена src не срабатывает только на img в header. Если просто обновлять, каждый раз по разному. В основном не делает замену в header и первых 1-3 проходах цикла где img с ошибкой.  После обновления страницы пару десятков раз, все работает.

Подскажите почему так происходит и как исправить? Или есть какой-нибудь альтернативный способ?

```js
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
    jQuery('img').on('error', function(){   
        jQuery(this).attr("src", "images/error_image.png");
    });

    jQuery('body').css("visibility","visible");
});
```

```php
    <header class="header">
        <img src="images/kek.png"/>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Обо мне</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Контакты</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="main_section">
        <div class="main_list">
            <ul>
                <?php
                    include("includes/db_connect.php");
                    $query="SELECT * FROM projects";
                    $result= mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                    while ($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        echo '
                        <li>
                            <div>
                                <a href="'.$data["link"].'">
                                    <img src="images/'.$data["name"].'.png"/>
                                    <div class="img_after"></div>
                                    <div class="name_link">'.$data["name"].'</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        ';
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: я так понимаю, что в тот момент, когда выполняется Ваш скрипт, некоторые картинки уже бросили onerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте Ваш код перед закрывающим тегом `</body>`

```
<body>
  ...
  <script>
  $('img').on('error', function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Noimage.svg/739px-Noimage.svg.png')
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

```css
img {max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----->
<img src="/noimage/.png">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/18/6b/d2/186bd27aec856f02b5b92867ce0164ab.jpg">
<img src="/nomage/.png">
<img src="/noige/.jpg">
<img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-dynamic-pattern-wallpaper-vector_53876-59131.jpg">
<img src="/nage/">

<script>
$('img').on('error', function(){
  $(this).attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Noimage.svg/739px-Noimage.svg.png')
});
</script>
```

Comment: Есть инфа почему так происходит? Разве jQuery('document').ready() не должен работать после того как все загрузится?

Comment: @Kriker39, `document.ready` - говорит JQ и JS о том, что страница получена, в этот момент будет работать скрипт, `window.on('load')` говорит как раз о том, что всё загружено. В большинстве случаев, перед `</body>` обычно всё заканчивает и это можно отнести к тому, что все элементы отрендерелись (не загрузились, а именно отрендерились).